# Probability that the student can solve 5 of 7 problems on the exam

Tags: probability

A student prepares for an exam by studying a list of 12 problems. She can solve 9 of them. For the exam, the instructor selects 7 problems at random from the 12 on the list given to the students. What is the probability that the student can solve 5 of the 7 problems on the exam?

I am really confused by this problem. My first initial thought was to do:

(5 chose 7)(7 chose 0)/ (12 chose 7)

I am not 100% sure about this though.

Comment: I believe it should be (7 chose 5)(7 choose 2)/ (12 chose 7) is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your denominator is right. That's the total number of possible exams. In the numerator you want the total number of exams where the student can solve 5/7 problems. So you want to chose the set of solvable problems and then chose the set of not solvable problems.

Comment: so you're saying it should just be (5 choose 7) / (12 choose 7)?

Comment: That corresponds to choosing the solvable problems. You still have to chose the not solvable problems.

Comment: Okay. hm.. would that be (2 choose 0) because there will be 2 other problems that you can't solve?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the student to solve exactly $5$ problems out of the $7$, the exam must contain exactly $5$ out of the $7$ problems the student knows how to solve, and exactly $2$ of the other three problems.

How many different combinations are there?

Comment: Could you explain why you said "exactly 2 of the other three problems"? I understand the 5 out of 7 but I feel like I am missing the other half. My professor told me that the top if summed together should equal the denominator.

Comment: @user125627 Is the student gets exactly $5$ of $7$ questions right, what does he do on the other two?

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{12}{7}$ ways the instructor can choose $7$ questions from $12$.

As the student can solve $9$ of the $12$, unless the instructor picks the $3$ she can't solve (and $4$ others), then she will be able to solve at least $5$ of them.

There are $\binom{9}{4}$ ways to pick the questions like this.

Therefore the probability that the student can solve **at least** five of the questions is:

$$1-\frac{\binom{9}{4}}{\binom{12}{7}}$$

$$=1-\frac{126}{792}$$

$$=1-\frac{7}{44}$$

$$=\frac{37}{44}$$